# Remove duplication in xls file

Tags: list, loops, duplicates, xls

I am trying to write a python script that is able to take contents of each row in xls file,extract a list of words (having a specific pattern using rex) from it and compare this list with all lists extracted in all rows after the current row until the end of the file . and delete the rows which have the same list.
Note, the words in two lists may be unordered but still they are equals in contents.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is pretty similar to the removing similar elements from an unsorted array. What you have to do is to do a hashing of all the rows based on the number of words that match your regex, and then compare in each of these buckets for similarity.

That you make the code pretty scalable too.

```
     buckets={}
     for row in rows:
          if bucket[row.length] is None:
               bucket[row.length]={}
          bucket[row.length].append(row)
      #now do your matching 
      for bucket in buckets:
          #match and delete.
```